# Jenkins unable to access on-prem github repository

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins, openssl

How to access on-prem github from jenkins? I am getting Peer's Certificate error.

`git clone https://abcd.efgh.ijk.state.ih.us/DataLake/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://abcd.efgh.ijk.state.ih.us/DataLake/project.git/': Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.`

To test, I am able to ssh into the machine and I am able to git clone after I set 
 `git config --global http.sslverify false` and then it would prompt me to provide username and password. But I need Jenkins to be able to clone it.

After reading other posts about adding SSL certificate, I tried

`openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect abcd.efgh.ijk.state.ih.us:443`

Response looks like this

`CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
Certificate chain
 0 s:xxxxxxxx
   i:xxxxxxxx
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
YYYY/....
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=xxxxxxxx issuer=xxxxxx
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
SSL handshake has read 2557 bytes and written 415 bytes`

`New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is .....
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : .......
    Session-ID: .......
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: ..................
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1565710526
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)`
    `Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)`
`---`
`closed`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the SSL chain being not complete ([as in here](https://superuser.com/a/1408815/141))

If `otherdomain` is accessible from internet, you can analyze it with [`ssllabs.com/ssltest`](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) (in case there is a [TLS configuration issue](https://serverfault.com/a/952231/783))
And you can get you chain certificates through [`whatsmychaincert.com`](https://whatsmychaincert.com/)

You will need to add those to the [Jenkins JVM trustore](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203821254-How-to-install-a-new-SSL-certificate-).

Answer (score 0):

It would also be a good idea to check your proxy server settings along with git/opnssl settings. It resolved my issue just by updating latest proxy address.